# Use declarative approach to shift ArrayList elements instead of using a loop

Tags: java, functional-programming, declarative-programming

Could you please point out a way to shift the elements of the list below, without using a for loop? Please note that the first element of the list is not affected by the operation performed.
From [2, 3, 4, 5] the list would become [2, 2, 3, 4]

```
List<BigDecimal> items = Arrays.asList(new BigDecimal(2), new BigDecimal(3), new BigDecimal(4), new BigDecimal(5));
for (int i = items.size() - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
    items.set(i, items.get(i - 1));
}
```

Comment: Shift where? Why don't you want to use `for` loop? Are you fine using `while` loop? You need to mention all these important points when you post a question.

Comment: In addition to Arvind Kumar Avinash comment, if you can, please clarify why you need to shift elements that are stored in a list. You delete the first one? Someone might have a better solution an you may don't even have to shift them.

Comment: You want to shift to the right the list and after substitute the element at index 0 with the old first element of the list like [2, 3, 4, 5] -> [2, 2, 3, 4] ?

Comment: I wont modify the first element. I was looking for a declarative approach using Java 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, try this.

- requires subList method.  (the reason for the new ArrayList<>() call)
- rotates left 1 item.

```
        List<BigDecimal> items = new ArrayList<>(
                Arrays.asList(new BigDecimal(2), new BigDecimal(3),
                        new BigDecimal(4), new BigDecimal(5)));
        List<BigDecimal> list = items.subList(1, items.size());
        list.add(items.get(0));
        System.out.println(list);
```

Prints

```
[3, 4, 5, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the following one-liner:

```
(items = Arrays.asList(items.get(0))).addAll(items);
```

Comment: Yes, that is true.